# CSV to text file layout

Tags: python, csv, text

I am outputting two columns of a CSV file to a text file and its printing everything on a single line in the text file. Like this:

```
Product Name Counter({'Descriptions': 1, 'Descriptions':3})
```

But I want it to print out like this:

```
Product Name Counter({'Descriptions': 1,

                      'Descriptions': 3})
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import csv  
import sys 
from collections import defaultdict 
from collections import Counter 
data = defaultdict(list) 

class dictionary: 
    with open ('practice.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader, None) 
        for row in reader:
            data[row[2]].append(row[3]) 


    text_file = open("test.txt", "w")
    data_count = Counter()
    for key in data.keys():  
        sys.stdout = text_file 
        print key, Counter(data[key])
    text_file.close()
```

How can I get my text file not to print out on one line?
Not sure how to get this to work.

Comment: have you tried adding the newline character (`'\n'`) at the end of your print statement?

Comment: yes I have tried ( '\n' ) and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The `Counter({'Descriptions': 1, 'Descriptions':3})` stuff is the output of the Counter's `__str__()` function.  When you use `print Counter(stuff)`, then this is implicitely called for a new object generated by `Counter(stuff)`.  If I understand correctly, you want to reformat this output.

You could do it by storing the output of `Counter(data[key])` in a variable and then modify that output by adding newlines at all positions of the `,` in the output:

```
a = str(Counter(data[key]))
print '\n'.join(a.split(','))
```

Which would be quite ugly ;-)

You could, however, design your ouptut yourself: The keys of the Counter are accessible via `a.keys()`, so you could add a loop:

```
a = Counter(data[key])
print key, 'Counter({',
for counter_key in a.keys():
    print counter_key + ': ' + a[counter_key] + ','
print '})'
```

which iterates over the content of the counter and outputs the key-value combination from your Counter line by line.

Edit:
The second part of your code would then look like this:

```
text_file = open("test.txt", "w")
for key in data.keys():
    text_file.writelines(key + ' Counter({')
    counted = Counter(data[key])
    for counter_key in counted.keys():
        text_file.writelines('  ' + counter_key + ': ' + counted[counter_key] + '\n')
    text_file.writelines('})\n')
text_file.close()
```

Note: It's possible to iterate over the key/value pairs in the counter using

```
for counter_key, counter_value in counted.items():
```

Comment: I am having trouble implementing what you suggested. Can you show me your code added to mine?

Comment: I updated my answer; see in the edit.  Please note, that this might contain bugs as I don't have a file to test...  Also note, that I did not use print but writelines() instead, which is intended to write to file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a new line at the end of each line with \n

Also have you tried adding rows with data.writer ?

```
import csv
with open('practice.csv', 'wb') as f:
    data = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    data.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    data.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

adapted from example here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: How about building up the csv line by line as follows: data.writerow(<row contents>) see further here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html